# How do i returns all records in sqlite using python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i have five records in the database with id equal to 1
but when i try to select only first one shown

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('IMG.db')
c = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM IMGCODE where id=1"
retrieved = pickle.loads(c.execute(sql).fetchone()[0])
print(retrieved)
c.close()
conn.close()
```

so how can i returns all five records?

Comment: What did you expect if you `fetchone()`?

Comment: i tried this one and this error is shown TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `fetchall()` instead of `fetchone()`

Comment: i tried this one and this error is shown TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

Comment: sure you get that error because it returns tuple (```fetchone()```) or list of tuple (```fetchall()```)

Comment: so what should i do to return all records ?

Comment: method ```pickle.loads``` accepts bytes but you are trying to put tuple into that method.

Comment: so why fetchone works fine but fetchall can't work i'm clueless, could you help me?

Comment: because ```fetchone()``` returns one tuple, but ```fetchall()`` returns list of tuples. and if you do following ```fetchone()[0]``` you get first column from your query (it's a byte), but when you type  ```fetchall()[0]``` you received one tuple. when you use fetchall() you have to loop through the result.

Comment: could you write an example, and i will be thankful to you

Comment: something lite this ```for row in cursor.fetchall():
    pickle.loads(row[0])```